# websphere 7 backwards compatibility

Tags: backwards-compatibility, weblogic-10.x, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

I am migrating a JSF application from WebSphere(WAS) 6.1 to WAS 7.0 and I am experiencing html deprecation issues now that I am using the JSP 2.1 API provided with WAS 7.0 as opposed to the JSP 2.0 API provided with WAS 6.1.  Weblogic provides the ability to enable backward compatibility (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13754/compat.htm#i1111538) in the weblogic app deployment descriptor.  Is there a similar solution available in WAS 7.0?  Is there a way to enable backwards compatibility in a deployment descriptor so the application can use JSF 2.0 API and not face the deprecated html issues?

Comment: I think it should read "JSP 2.0 API" instead of "JSF 2.0 API" in the last sentence. JSF 2.0 isn't supported by WebSphere 7.0.

Comment: Yes you are correct that was a spelling error thanks for catching!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing conclusive about this in the WebSphere Application Server 7.0 documentation, therefore I am led to believe that the typical IBM strategy is used here: The JSP engine you're getting with WAS 7.0 is JSP 2.1 compatible, period. You can't replace it and can't instruct WAS to use an older specification level.

Comment: Thank you for the response as well I did not see anything related to this in the WAS 7 documentation.